# how can we use scipy.signal.resample to downsample the speech signal from 44100 to 8000 Hz signal?

Tags: python, scipy

```
fs, s = wav.read('wave.wav')
```

This signal has 44100 Hz sampleing frquency, I want to donwnsample this signal to 8Khz using 
`scipy.signal.resample(s,s.size/5.525)` but the second element can't be float, so, how can we use this function for resmapling the speech signal?

How we can use `scipy.signal.resample` to downsample the speech signal from 44100 to 8000 Hz in python?

Answer (score 7):

Okay then, another solution, this one with scipy for real. Just what asked for.

This is the **doc** string of scipy.signal.resample():

```
"""
Resample `x` to `num` samples using Fourier method along the given axis.

The resampled signal starts at the same value as `x` but is sampled
with a spacing of ``len(x) / num * (spacing of x)``.  Because a
Fourier method is used, the signal is assumed to be periodic.

Parameters
----------
x : array_like
    The data to be resampled.
num : int
    The number of samples in the resampled signal.
t : array_like, optional
    If `t` is given, it is assumed to be the sample positions
    associated with the signal data in `x`.
axis : int, optional
    The axis of `x` that is resampled.  Default is 0.
window : array_like, callable, string, float, or tuple, optional
    Specifies the window applied to the signal in the Fourier
    domain.  See below for details.

Returns
-------
resampled_x or (resampled_x, resampled_t)
    Either the resampled array, or, if `t` was given, a tuple
    containing the resampled array and the corresponding resampled
    positions.

Notes
-----
The argument `window` controls a Fourier-domain window that tapers
the Fourier spectrum before zero-padding to alleviate ringing in
the resampled values for sampled signals you didn't intend to be
interpreted as band-limited.

If `window` is a function, then it is called with a vector of inputs
indicating the frequency bins (i.e. fftfreq(x.shape[axis]) ).

If `window` is an array of the same length as `x.shape[axis]` it is
assumed to be the window to be applied directly in the Fourier
domain (with dc and low-frequency first).

For any other type of `window`, the function `scipy.signal.get_window`
is called to generate the window.

The first sample of the returned vector is the same as the first
sample of the input vector.  The spacing between samples is changed
from dx to:

    dx * len(x) / num

If `t` is not None, then it represents the old sample positions,
and the new sample positions will be returned as well as the new
samples.

"""
```

As you should know, 8000 Hz means that one second of your signal contains 8000 samples, and for 44100 Hz, it means that one second contains 44100 samples.

Then, just calculate how many samples do you need for 8000 Hz and use the number as an second argument to scipy.signal.resample().

You may use the method that Nathan Whitehead used in a resample function that I coppied in other answer (with scaling),

or go through time i.e.

```
secs = len(X)/44100.0 # Number of seconds in signal X
samps = secs*8000     # Number of samples to downsample
Y = scipy.signal.resample(X, samps)
```

Answer (score 0):

This I picked from SWMixer module written by Nathan Whitehead:

```
import numpy

def resample(smp, scale=1.0):
    """Resample a sound to be a different length
    Sample must be mono.  May take some time for longer sounds
    sampled at 44100 Hz.

    Keyword arguments:
    scale - scale factor for length of sound (2.0 means double length)
    """
    # f*ing cool, numpy can do this with one command
    # calculate new length of sample
    n = round(len(smp) * scale)
    # use linear interpolation
    # endpoint keyword means than linspace doesn't go all the way to 1.0
    # If it did, there are some off-by-one errors
    # e.g. scale=2.0, [1,2,3] should go to [1,1.5,2,2.5,3,3]
    # but with endpoint=True, we get [1,1.4,1.8,2.2,2.6,3]
    # Both are OK, but since resampling will often involve
    # exact ratios (i.e. for 44100 to 22050 or vice versa)
    # using endpoint=False gets less noise in the resampled sound
    return numpy.interp(
        numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, n, endpoint=False), # where to interpret
        numpy.linspace(0.0, 1.0, len(smp), endpoint=False), # known positions
        smp, # known data points
        )
```

So, if you are using scipy, that means that you have numpy too. If scipy is not "a MUST#, use this, it works perfectly.

Comment: I don't see a low-pass filter to prevent aliasing when downsampling (i.e. `scale` < 1).  If `smp` has frequency content that is more than half the sampling rate of the downsampled signal, the result will contain the garbage that comes from sampling those frequencies at too low a rate.

Comment: Yes, it will, but filtering can be done separately, before interpolation. And, intended use is for speech, so, unless someone suddenly starts to sing it will hold. Garbage will be noticeable if symphonic orchestra is recorded and downsampled. Other garbage is tolerable.

Answer (score 0):

this code if you want to resample all wav files in some folder:

```
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
from scipy.io import wavfile
from scipy.signal import resample

def scip_rs(file):
    try:
        sr, wv = wavfile.read(file)
        if sr==16000:
            pass
        else:
            sec = len(wv)/sr
            nsmp = int(sec*16000)+1
            rwv = resample(wv, nsmp)
            wavfile.write(file, 16000, rwv/(2**15-1))
    except Exception as e:
        print('Error in file : ', file)
for file in tqdm(np.array(df.filepath.tolist())):
    scip_rs(file)
```